# remove item from List<String> in android

Tags: android, list, arraylist

I have an List i.e  tag_complaints1 that contain value like:

```
[#nasikPolice, #mnc, #awaaz, #college, #principal, #stalking, #eve_teasing, #bad_touch, #domestic_violence, #nasik, #help, #muncipal]
```

After selecting data from multiAutoCompleteTextView get data like:

```
[#principal #b #awaaz ]
```

by using this

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(tag_name);
```

now I want to remove `#principal` `#awaaz` from List items which are already present in tag_complaints1 & get only `#b` from List items.

```
      tag_name = multiAutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString();
            Log.d(TAG,"selected tags are:"+tag_name);

            if (!tag_complaints.contains(tag_name)){

                final DocumentReference documentReference7 = firebaseFirestore.collection("Button").document("Tag_option");
                documentReference7.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                            if (document != null) {
                                tag_complaints1 = (List<String>) document.get("Tags");
                                ArrayList<String> tempList= new ArrayList<String>();

                                List<String> items = Arrays.asList(tag_name);
                                Log.d(TAG,"getted string List"+items);


                                //documentReference7.update("Tags", FieldValue.arrayUnion(new_tag_name));


                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting data from multiAutoCompleteTextView it is necessary to be split by using:

> List list = (Arrays.asList(tag_name.split(" "));

then perform removing operation like:

```
    //remove common element
                                for (String removestring : tag_complaints1) {
                                    if (list.contains(removestring)) {
                                        //filter item from list
                                        list.remove(removestring);
                                    }

                                }
                                Log.d(TAG,"after removing list"+list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `List#removeAll`:

```
if (document != null) {
    tag_complaints1 = (List<String>) document.get("Tags");
    ArrayList<String> tempList= new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList(tag_name);
    Log.d(TAG, "getted string List" + items);
    // CHANGE HERE:
    items.removeAll(tag_complaints1);
}
```

Comment: it should not work  after removing result=[#principal #stalking #a]